# How to limit application into specific scope (Windows)

Tags: windows, permissions, restrictions

I have an application that perform some specific system calls. For example, tries to get MAC address of NIC. Or info about running processes. I don't want to allow this, but I have to allow to use networking (TCP/IP stack) by this app.
Is it possible to restrict access for some specific scopes of my PC? (Sorry, I don't know how to call it).
Is it possible to restrict all and allow access only for specific dirs, files, reg keys and networking?
I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: No, not by default. What you are describing is a Mandatory Access Control system (MAC), whereas Windows by default uses Role Based Access Control (RBAC). In linux you can do stuff like this with SELunix or  AppArmor, In Windows there are some access control frameworks like Avecto, but I've never dealt with one that will do what you request, as it would essentially need to replace UAC with itself.

Comment: MAC here it is Media Access Control, sorry. But you have a good idea.

Comment: @Jury - Frank is well aware of that.  Your comment doesn't really change his response though.

Comment: Without knowing how the app behaves when it is unable to query information it expects then it's hard to say if this is possible for this app.  Look into the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit. This enables you to create shims (sdb files that can be installed using sdbinst.exe) to "lie" to applications.  For example, using the VirtualRegistry "fix", you can make an application that is looking under HKLM\software\app\ to look under HKLM\software\app2\ for example.  Process Monitor can also help to understand how the application queries the data you want to hide/falsify.

Comment: Ok, after ProcMon research how can I block something? Is there something except MACT?

Comment: The thing I think you are neglecting to consider is that in windows, processes always run with the permissions associated with the user account executing them. The app itself actually has nothing to do with it. Processes may be invoked as low, medium, or high integrity, and an app may state the minimum integrity level it will execute with, but I know of no way to set the maximum integrity level. if an admin-approval capable user elects to run an app as admin, the app has no control over that, and will execute with the rights that user has for high integrity procs (if any).